# If loop - checking previous value against new one

Tags: loops, if-statement

There are no dumb questions - that is my moto. Here goes.
I know it simple but I just can´t seem to fully understand, what makes the difference between:

```
double previousLocation = e.getX();
    if (e.getX() != previousLocation);
```

and, changing the location of the to variables

```
 double previousLocation = e.getX();
    if (previousLocation != e.getX());
```

e.getX simply sets the location of the mouse on the screen. and I have an graphical object wich follows my mouse movement. In the first example it works, in the second it does not work.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  In a single-threaded environment, neither of these if-statements should evaluate to true.  What is updating `e`?  And do the two lines of code actually appear together, or have you omitted a bunch of code in between?  Does the `e.getX()` call have a side-effect that changes the value of `previousLocation`?

Comment: e is an user interface event and is constantly being updated as the user moves the mouse. So when the user moves the mouse - that value is not equal to the previousValue. And I move an object to the new mouse location

Comment: What is the signature of getX() ?

Comment: I realized I got some buggy logic, this IF statement basically does nothing. it Only worked since i had the ";" after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
previousLocation != e.getX()
```

is equivalent to

```
e.getX() != previousLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference here is WHEN you call e.getX() the second time. If you put it in the second part of the if statement, e.getX() is going to be evaluated slightly later. In this time the mouse may have moved slightly more, messing up your vague intentions.

Another thing to consider is that doubles in most languages are not 100% accurate and when comparing doubles like you are, you should use an epsilon:

```
double epsilon = 0.0000001;
if(previousLocation>=e.getX()-epsilon && previousLocation<= e.getX()+epsilon)
   //evaluate
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usual to store the previous location AFTER having determined that it has changed.

```
void EventHandler( MouseEvent & e )
{
    static double previousLocation = e.getX();
    double currentLocation = e.getX();

    if( previousLocation != currentLocation ) {
        // Take whatever action you need to
        //...

        previousLocation = currentLocation;
    } 
}
```